# Decode JSON package from PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am building a simple login system. I do not want the page to reload when the user submits the form, in case there is an error, and I need to seamlessly display an error message (Like wrong password). When the users submits the data, AJAX passes it onto the submit.php script. This script validates the data and then sets a JSON object to a number 1-3 based on what is wrong or right with the submitted credentials. I don't know how to have the AJAX call, decode the JSON, and then have some `if` statements that decide what to do based on the value of that JSON.

Below is the code I am using for the form.

HTML:

```
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
                 <h1 class="title" unselectable="on">Login</h1>
                     <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" class="form" id="username"/>
                     </br>
                     <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" class="form" id="password"/> 
                     </br>  
                         <input class="button" type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit"/>
                     </br>
    </form>
```

JS/AJAX (Same page):

```
    function SubmitFormData() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.post("submit.php", { username: username, password: password},
    function(data) {
     $('#results').html(data);
     $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    });
}
```

Next is the PHP (submit.php). The PHP will look at the incoming data from the AJAX script, and then assign an error number to a JSON object depending on what is wrong with the credentials.

```
           $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);  
           $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);  
           $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                {  
                     if(password_verify($password, $row["password"]))
                     {  
                          $Obj->error = "three";
                          $myJSON = json_encode($Obj);
                     }  
                     else  
                     {  
                            $Obj->error = "two";
                            $myJSON = json_encode($Obj);
                     }  
                }  
           }
           else {
               $Obj->error = "one";
               $myJSON = json_encode($Obj);
           }
           
           //error one=user not found
           //error two=wrong password
           //error three=all detials are correct
```

Now, the trouble I am having is back at the main page where the user is. I want the JS to look at the $myJSON variable and decide what to do based on that. I have written some pseudo code below, but I don't know if or how I can do this in JS or AJAX.

```
decode JSON package
if error=one, do something
if error=two, do something else
if error=three, run a php script that sets some session variables. (Is it possible to run php inside of JS?)
```

Any help accomplishing these results would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your response data is JSON coming back from the PHP code you don't want to `.html(data)` turn it into HTML, you just want to `somevar = JSON.parse(data)` to create a javascript variable that holds the object/array/whatever that was returned. But that aside — writing your own login/password management is a security nightmare; I don't know what `password_verify()` does, but if it doesn't involve a one-way cryptographic salted hash it's probably insecure. Telling someone the password is wrong tells them the login name is right, which helps hackers. Tell them invalid user/password _combination_

Comment: @StephenP I will make that change to invalid combination. ```password_verify()``` is a one way salted hash. https://www.php.net/password_hash Here is the documentation on it.

Comment: save .js as .php and make variabes inside.

Comment: Note you aren't preventing the default form submit process so your page will reload when you submit

Comment: How would I prevent that? @charlietfl

Comment: Read up on how to pass event to your function and use `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a vanilla javascript solution:

```
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    //passes results to a function
    start(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "PHP WEBSITE URL", true);
//sends the request with a FormData object based on the form
xmlhttp.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm")));

function start(object) {
  alert(object);
}
```

For this to work, your PHP script will have to `echo` your result object. Example:

```php
if ($_POST["username"] === "correctUsername" && $_POST["password"] === "correctPassword") {
  //echo javascript object
  echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);
} else {
  //echo javascript object
  echo json_encode(['success'=>false]);
}
```

Obviously it needs to be more complex but this is the idea.

I have made login pages before and instead of returning a success I used the current PHP page as the main one and echoed the info to fill the page as well as credentials that can be used with AJAX requests. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: In the Javascript, where does it look for true or false in the PHP file and then do something based on that?

Comment: At the `start` function the `object` parameter is the object returned by PHP. You can do `if(object.success){success();}else{failed();}`

Comment: Those echos are not valid JSON. Never a good idea to manually create it

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I know it is not a good idea as I could echo the direct result but he wanted a JSON object for some reason

Comment: Fine but the way the string is written it isn't valid json and will fail getting parsed client side. Better to do `echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);`